# How to replace text with binary code in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a question about `gen` and `replace`.

If I have the data

```
var1
female
female

male
female
male
female
male
male
female
female
male
female
female
female

male
male
male
male
male
female
male
male
male
female
female
female
male
male
female
female
male
male
male
female
female
male
male
male
```

and am hoping to replace the text `female` with 1 and `male` with 0. How do I do this?

I have tried:

```
. replace var1 = 1 if female
female not found
r(111);
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

```
generate byte female = (var1 == "female") if inlist(var1, "female", "male")
generate byte male = (var1 == "male") if inlist(var1, "female", "male")
```

Comment: Fine, but in practice you only need one of those for most purposes.